# How to use DKIM with TidSMTP client?

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy, dkim, spf

I am sending notifications emails thorugh a TidSMTP client based application.

When recieving messages I send in gmail I see the warning "this email could not have been sent by name@domain.com".

Google itself suggests to use DKIM or SPF to prevent the problem.

As far as I researched SPF is not a free service, so I would rather go for a free option. (please correct me if I am wrong).

Does anyone already did the same? What to do?

Comment: With some Python or Java code, you could use Google App Engine as a mail gateway from your Delphi app. Basic accounts are free and allow to send mail to 100 recipients/day.

Comment: Ok 100 recipients/day could be not enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

[SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) is not a service, so I don't know what kind of research you were looking at. [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) and [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) are authentication schemes used by SMTP servers to verify the sender really is who it claims to be.  SPF relies on special entries added to DNS records. DKIM relies on digital signatures added to email.

Comment: Ok, the research I am doing means that I faced the problem and now I was redirected to those keywords. SPF is anyway something I should pay for, so this is why I asked mainly for DKIM. Now I asked here to see if there is something already ready, or being redirected somewhere I can find more help without studying pages of specs.

Comment: There is nothing implemented in Indy to support DKIM.  You have to implement it yourself. SPF support is available in TIdSMTPServer, though you have to implement the actual validations yourself.